# SHChangeNotify doesn't refresh icons in C# exe, but does in powershell command prompt, Windows Server 2019

Tags: c#, powershell, icons

This powershell code does refresh the desktop and file icons, if I paste it into a powershell command prompt, on Windows Server 2019:

```
  $code = @'
  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Shell32.dll")] 
  private static extern int SHChangeNotify(int eventId, int flags, IntPtr item1, IntPtr item2);

  public static void Refresh()  {
      SHChangeNotify(0x8000000, 0x1000, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);    
  }
'@

Add-Type -MemberDefinition $code -Namespace WinAPI -Name Explorer 
[WinAPI.Explorer]::Refresh()
```

But if I run an executable based on that exact same C# code, it doesn't work:

```
namespace RefreshShell
{
    class Program
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
        private static extern int SHChangeNotify(int eventId, int flags, IntPtr item1, IntPtr item2);

        public static void Refresh()
        {
            SHChangeNotify(0x8000000, 0x1000, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Refresh();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

It just makes the desktop icons flash once, but they remain with the old icon image.

I'm running as administrator.

Also, if I run the powershell code as script (eg `C:\path\refreshShell.ps1`), it doesn't work, same as the C# exe.

But if I run it by pasting the following command in command prompt, then it does work:

`powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -File "C:\path\refreshShell.ps1" -FFFeatureOff`

What's going on here? Why don't these other ways of running it work, even though I'm running as administrator? I have a feeling it has to do with that "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass" option; but I don't know how to apply that to a C# executable.

Ultimately, I need to get the icons to refresh after installing a new exe with a new icon, using an NSIS installer.

**
Update: I just tested the C# exe on Windows 10, and it worked. And I wasn't even running as administrator there. So I feel like this is some kind of group policy issue or extra security thing on Windows Server 2019. Also, this is an AWS instance; although I doubt that matters.

Comment: When running in PS script or in Visual Studio you have to right click the PS shortcut (or VS shortcut) and select Run As Admin.  When running from a c# executable the code will automatically run As Admin.

Comment: @jdweng: The original premise of the question was that the PowerShell code is already being run with elevation (as admin). If what you're saying about C#-based applications _were_ true, your comment would be _unnecessary_.
Because your claim about C# applications _isn't true_, your comment is _misleading_: No .NET application (whether created with C# or a different .NET language) runs with elevation _by default_ - an explicitly crafted application manifest requesting elevation is necessary. You've made this incorrect claim before - please stop.

Comment: Tomas: You indeed shouldn't need elevation to call the function. I don't know if it makes a difference, but note that the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shchangenotify) state that you should pass `SHCNF_IDLIST` as the `uFlags` argument, whose value is `0x0`, not `0x1000`

Comment: @mklement0 : The OP is login as Admin but VS and Power Shell do not run as Admin unless you right click and select Run As Admin.

Comment: @jdweng, saying "I'm running as administrator" - while technically ambiguous - _usually_ means _running with elevation_  (not just as a user who happens to be an adminstrator), and the OP's premise is that running this way (whatever the interpretation) _worked from PowerShell_, but _not from a C#-based application_. Nothing in your comments addresses this problem, and, to repeat the more important point made in my previous comment: Please stop claiming that "running from a c# executable the code will automatically run As Admin".